# Delete overlapping identical surfaces in CATIA using VBA

Tags: vba, catia

I have a file that contains many identical surfaces overlapped. How could I check if two surfaces are identical and overlapped and delete one of them using VBA functions?

Comment: There's no direct way in VBA because the Automation API hardly contains methods to read the mathematical description of surfaces or curves. Without that it is difficult to check whether two surfaces or two curves are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gdir said there is no direct way.

However you can compare some properties which you can measure such as surface area, length of boundary, number of verticies on the boundary, various extremum points, center of gravity, moments of inertia, etc.

Although these properties don't mathematically prove or disprove that two surfaces are the identical/different in most cases some combination of them will suffice.

Comment: Another (complicated) way would be to save the part as IGES and then search for duplicates in the IGES file. Collect the names of the duplicates and use them to delete the features in the CATIA part.